# Show a popover for a UIButton in a static UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift, uibutton, popover

I have a popover when I tap on a UIButton.  This button is in a static UITableViewCell.  Howeever when I tap on the button, the popover isn't where I would think it should, under the UIButton.

Because it's a static cell I am not using didSelectRowAtIndexPath nor do I need to use cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I'm basically using the UITableView as a cheap alternative to embedding a scroll view inside my view controller.  It's essentially for data entry.  I have 4 sections, and each section has 1 row.  I believe I need to figure out how to get the NSIndexPath from the row in each section to pass to the .sourceView  something similar to this in Objective-C

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.profileItemsDetailPopover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


@IBAction func dateOfBirthAction(sender: AnyObject){

    var popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DateOfBirthViewController") as UIViewController
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(300, 300)

    let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = tableView
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = playerInformationBirthDateButton.frame

    presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Solution:**

```
@IBAction func dateOfBirthAction(sender: UIButton){

    var cell = sender.superview!.superview! as UITableViewCell

    var popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DateOfBirthViewController") as UIViewController
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(300, 300)

    let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = cell.contentView
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = playerInformationBirthDateButton.frame

    presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thanks..it works for me as well..How do i give pointer on exact cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also find out the "Cell" when you click on the Button.

```
var cell = sender.superview!.superview! as UITableViewCell
// or the table
var table: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
// or the Indexpath
let indexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)
```

Comment: I had to tweak your solution a bit, but it works.  Will edit and add solution.  Thanks!!